# How is the exaltation degree and the exaltation rashi determined for a graha?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, horary-astrology

It's a common knowledge that BPHS (Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra) assigns a specific Rashi and degree for the exaltation and debilitation of every graha. For instance, moon gets exalted at 3 degrees of Taurus, or Mars gets exalted at 28 degrees of Capricorn. Can any expert from jyotisha shashtra explain how these degrees and signs are arrived at?

Comment: The experts know that such and such is the point of exaltation/debilitation for a particular Graha only because texts like BPHS say so .. Otherwise they would not be having any clues

Comment: @rickross: I wonder how our perspective towards jyotisha would change if we could grasp these fundamentals properly. Because explanations to these would come directly from depths of primal concepts which depict existence The way it is.

Comment: Yes I understand ur point but I am not sure whether such explanations are found some where or not

Comment: @rickross: Yes, I agree. Thanks for replying :)